# intern 2 configuration for BrowserStack behind a proxy

Tags: intern, browserstack

I'm unsure what the configuration should be running intern 2 tests against BrowserStack when running behind a proxy/firewall and currently seeing errors/timeouts.

My Current configuration is:

```
proxyPort : 9000,
proxyUrl : 'http://localhost:9000',
tunnel : 'BrowserStackLocal',
tunnelOptions : {
    username : 'myusername',
    accessKey : 'myaccesskey',
    hostname : '<myproxyip>',
    proxy : 'http://<myproxyip>:<myproxyport>'
}
```

I don't think I need `hostname` however if I remove that I immediately see the error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`.

If use the above configuration it seems to get further, waits for a while then see:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
BrowserStackLocal v3.3
Connecting to BrowserStack using WebSocket protocol...
Connected.
Ready
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@<myproxyip>:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ETIMEDOUT
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
   at errnoException  <net.js:904:11>
   at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:895:19>
FATAL ERROR
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@<myproxyip>:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ETIMEDOUT
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
   at errnoException  <net.js:904:11>
```

The `[POST http://(redacted)@<myproxyip>:4444/wd/hub/session]` url doesn't seem right. Obviously I have this misconfigured & would appreciate any advice. I do struggle to understand intern's documentation when running behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are behind some kind of proxy.

When you are behind proxy server, in order to use Intern with BrowserStack, you need to do two things:

1. Get Local Testing connection to work with your proxy, which you are doing, and you can see success message.
2. You have to make sure the node process that runs the Intern test works with your proxy. To enable proxy in a node application, the easiest option is to use global-tunnel npm package. There is a step-by-step guide available [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/global-tunnel).

Would love to answer any queries you might have! Do drop in a mail at support@browserstack.com

Umang,
BrowserStack Support.

Comment: Umang, thanks for the reply however unfortunately this is an intern configuration problem & don't see it documented. I have been able to run wd.js tests against my local environment through a proxy so all is fine in that regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think there is a bug in `browserStack.js`. Some proxy support is missing there I think. When I use configuration `browserstack_conf.js` as shown below tests run okay but there is an error message when Browserstack tries to publish the test results back to www.browserstack.com

```
[09:43:06] E/launcher - connect ETIMEDOUT 54.152.200.70:443
[09:43:06] E/launcher - Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.152.200.70:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
[09:43:06] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I can fix this error with following steps:

1. `npm install -g http-proxy-agent`
2. Edit `browserStack.js` (located for example in `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Romaing\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\` add a `require` for this and initialize a `agent` and add to `request`.

For example add `require` top of `browserStack.js`

```
var HttpProxyAgent = require('http-proxy-agent');
```

And change the section with `options` to

```
            let options = {
                hostname: 'www.browserstack.com',
                port: 443,
                path: '/automate/sessions/' + session.getId() + '.json',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: headers//,
                agent: new HttpProxyAgent('http://myproxy:3128')
            };
```

I start Protractor with configuration below

```
// browserstack.conf.js

var browserstack = require('browserstack-local');

exports.config = {
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  webDriverProxy: 'http://myproxy:3128',
  browserstackUser: 'myuser',
  browserstackKey: '*****',
  capabilities: {
    project: 'BrowserStack (beyond Proxy)',
    browserName: 'Chrome',
    browser_version: '50.0',
    os: 'OS X',
    os_version: 'Yosemite',
    'browserstack.local': true,
    'browserstack.debug': true    
  }, 
  // Code to start browserstack local before start of test
  beforeLaunch: function(){
    console.log("Connecting local");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      exports.bs_local = new browserstack.Local();
      exports.bs_local.start({'key': '*****',     
     'proxyHost': 'myproxy', 'proxyPort': '3128',    
      'binarypath': 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Downloads\\BrowserStackLocal-win32\\BrowserStackLocal.exe'},
       function(error) {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        console.log('Connected. Now testing...');

        resolve();

      });
    });
  },

  // Code to stop browserstack local after end of test
  afterLaunch: function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     exports.bs_local.stop(resolve);
   });
  } 
};
```